# Quick Answer Verification: When are two Norms/Operator Norms Equal

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This is just a question that I've been thinking about, but not sure what to do:
From Naylor and Sell, 
Let X and Y be normed linear spaces and let T be a bounded linear transformation of X into Y.  We define the norm of T to be

$||T||$=inf {${M:||Tx||_Y \leq M||x||_X \mbox{for all x} \in X}$}.
Let X=Y=$R^{n}$ with norm $||x||_1$.
I guess then we have that (not entirely sure):

1. $||T||$=inf {${M:||Tx||_1 \leq M||x||_1 \mbox{for all x} \in X}$}

Then, we are also given that $M_n$ is the space of real n x n matrices. For

2. $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_n$, we define $n(A)$=$\sum_{i,j}^{} |a_{ij}| $.

My question is then when is 1 equal to 2 and how do they relate.  I know that $||T||$ is the operator norm, or the matrix induced norm by the vector 1-norm.  Hence it is equal to the maximum absolute column sum.  I believe $n(A)$ is just the sum of the absolute  value of all the entries.  So wouldn't this just imply that $n(A)\geq ||T|| $, with equality only occurring when we have one column with nonzero entries and the rest of the columns all having 0 as entries.  The problem I'm having is whether I'm interpreting $||T||$ and $n(A)$ correctly. I'm not too familiar with this notation:$\sum_{i,j}^{} |a_{ij}| $.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$ is just shorthand for $\sum_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|$, where the ranges of $i$ and $j$ in the summations are as appropriate. So you're right, it's the sum of the absolute values of all the entries.

Comment: @Rahul , thanks, so does this just mean the sum of all the entries of a Matrix A or only over a certain row/column range?

Comment: When the range is omitted, it essentially means "for all (reasonable) values of $i$ and $j$". For example if you're summing over a $3\times3$ matrix this would mean $\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3|a_{ij}|$.

Comment: @Rahul, I see so basically summing the absolute value of all the entries.  With that being said, is my answer right with regards to the equality/relationship of $||T||$ and $n(A)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is entirely correct. In general, to work with operator norms it s better to think of them as $$\|T\|=\sup\{\|Tx\|:\ \|x\|=1\}. $$

Comment: I see, thank you very much.  I've seen that definition of ||T|| as well as the definition of ||T|| where $||x|| \leq 1$

Comment: I've always understood operator norms to be defined as $||T|| = sup_{||x|| \neq 0} \frac{||Tx||}{||x||}$, how does this equal  $sup_{||x|| = 1}||Tx||$? Just curious :-).